# How to draw a grid of cards/elements with Polymer?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I am an Android developer trying to learn Dart-Polymer(I am also fairly new to HTML dev). I tried the [custom card example in the polymer tutorial](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-2.html), and as an extension I want to display multiple cards in a rectangular grid. I see there are horizontal and vertical layouts in Polymer, and **I was wondering if Polymer has something like GridView in Android**. Can someone suggest how to proceed ?

The grid on left is what I want to achieve :
[image]

The core-card is on the right. I can see that element in the designer (please see the panel in right under core). But I am unable to find the core-card in Polymer libraries. That's why I am going with custom card (from the tutorial mentioned above). I would like to use core-card if available.

After posting this question, I found out about [core-layout-grid](https://github.com/Polymer/core-layout-grid) - I am not sure how to use it, and if that's what I need.

Comment: I have no idea what the 'custom card example in the polymer tutorial' is and how 'multiple cards in a rectangular grid' should look like or what a 'GridView in Android' looks like. Can you please add at least links to what you referencing to. Maybe there is some example page that shows what you want.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer : Sorry, that was my bad ! I have updated my query with details. The core-card thing is not possibly related to this question, but would appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't know why the demo for core-layout-grid is not published to the elements page http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/ like all other elements. But you can find the source here https://github.com/Polymer/core-layout-grid/blob/master/demo.html, this might be useful too https://github.com/Polymer/core-layout-trbl/blob/master/core-layout-trbl.html

Comment: I can't post any code right now, but I'm pretty sure that if you put the cards in a container that has the width you want (2 cards plus gutter), and set the layout to horizontal, it should give you the grid pattern you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polymer has excellent handling to ease the use of [CSS FlexBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes). Using the various `layout`,`horizontal`,`vertical`, `wrap`, and `flex` attributes it is very easy to make very flexible and responsive layouts, including grids.

You can read more about the Layout attributes and their uses, including various alignment attributes from the [Polymer Layout Attributes](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout) page. In particular look at the [Wrapping](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html#wrapping) section as it helps to create responsive grids that will appropriately adjust based on the width of the display.